# Change a value of json variable in a php file

Tags: php

Hi i have a php file that contain json value. I want to change the value of json variable .But i am not sure how t do that .

**my-file.php**

```
<?
    $json_data;
    $json_varible = json_decode('{"pen_color":"red","book_size":"large","book_color":"red", etc etc }', true);
    ....
?>
```

Now I want to change the value of **pen_color to green** . **Please note there are many parameters in json_decode**

So i write following

```
//read the entire string
$str=file_get_contents('my-file.php');
$old_value= "red";
$new_value = "green";

//replace something in the file string - this is a VERY simple example
$str=str_replace($old_value, $new_value,$str);

file_put_contents('my-file.php', $str);
```

I am sure that this code is wrong. Please help me to solve the issue. I want t change **pen_color to green**

Comment: _"I am sure that this code is wrong"_ - the whole approach is. You don't mess around with JSON by doing string replacements. You decode the JSON, change whatever you need in the resulting data structure - and then you encode that modified structure as JSON again, and write it back to the file.

Comment: @CBroe could you please provide the solution. It will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is that you want

```
$json_variable = json_decode('{"pen_color":"red","book_size":"large","book_color":"red"}', true);
$json_variable['pen_color'] = 'green';
$json_value = json_encode($json_variable);

file_put_contents('my-file.php', $json_value );
```

Comment: Here the issue is there are lots of parameters inside json_varible  and i only want to replace value of pen_color

Comment: John made a typo. "$json_varible" should be "$json_variable".
This way you keep all the other JSON values, but still replacing pen_color.